# Asp.net Angular Template application Npm update does not work

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, asp.net-core

I am trying to follow the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) however it is going well. All of the packages that gets created with the application are out of date such as the `@angular/compiler` which really the version at the time of this post is `6.0.2` not `4.2.5` as listed below in the generated `packages.json`.

Things to note.

- Angular core 2.1 is installed
- Latest version of NPM and Node are installed
- Visual Studio 2017 Community is installed
- Operating System: Windows 10

With the packages being this out of date there are many angular things I can take advantage of. I have been looking around however I have not found any solutions that work.

Things I have tried:

- npm update
- npm update -D && npm update -S
- npm cache clean
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

My dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "TestingApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Update `dotnet --info`

**Product Information:**

Version:            2.1.201
Commit SHA-1 hash:  7932dc6179

**Runtime Environment:**

OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.17134
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.7
Build    : 2d61d0b043915bc948ebf98836fefe9ba942be11

Comment: It would seem that, despite installing the Core 2.1 SDK (you did install the SDK and not just the runtime, right?) that `dotnet new` is still using the old template. If you run `dotnet --info`, what versions of the SDK does that show are installed?

Comment: Ran the command.  The one version says 2.0.7 but the other product info says 2.1.

Comment: Perhaps, install the latest SDK (2.1.301) and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: No problem thank you for the information.